# Is webRTC supports remote machine screen sharing and controlling?

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc

it is possible to access & control my remote machine screen by using webRTC?? if possible can you please share the information regarding the above problem

Comment: On a protocol level, it’s just sending a video feed (which happens to originate from the contents of your screen) one way and control signals the other way. WebRTC can do that with its video and data channels. There’s nothing built into WebRTC for grabbing the screen or sending those control signals though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the WebRTC protocol allows it. The APIs in the browser don't provide this though.

[webrtc-remote-screen](https://github.com/rviscarra/webrtc-remote-screen) is a project that does this today.

Comment: DuBols, I tried  webrtc-remote-screen but it's not displaying any screens in the dropdown button. when i clicked the start button it's giving error(failed to fetch)